# How to get access token in apex scheduler for the same org?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, callout, oauth2

Can anyone will provide me example of how to get accesstoken in apex code which can be used for making rest callout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Create a connected app. Refer this link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_defining_remote_access_applications.htm

Copy client id and client secret from connected app you created.

There are several types of authentication. Here I used username password oauth flow.

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=YYYYYYYYY&username=yourusername&password=yourpassword');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
HttpResponse response = h.send(request);
System.debug('response '+response.getBody());
```

Replace "login" with "test" if you are trying in sandbox. Response will look like:

```
{"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Dxxxxxxxx/005xxxxxxxxx",
"issued_at":"1278448832702","instance_url":"https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/",
"signature":"xxxxxxxxxx=","access_token":
"00Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Get access token by parsing this json response.